# ROS2 Dashing cannot be installed because the public key is not available

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ros2

- OS: ubuntu 18.04
- Installation: ROS2 Dashing
- Installation date: 2021/05/29

Official documentation
"https://docs.ros.org/en/dashing/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html"

I tried to install it referring to the official documentation, but I can't get the apt repository because the public key isn't available.

```
W: GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG F42ED6FBAB17C654 Open Robotics <info@osrfoundation.org>
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried.

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add-
```

Another article said that doing this would solve it, so I did it, but it still didn't work.

```
sudo apt-key adv -keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com -recv-keys F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

Has there been another change recently?
please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a similar issue and for me, [this](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-gpg-keys-deployed-for-packages-ros-org/9454) fixed it. Basically, I had add the new repository key and delete the old one. Listing the commands here for convenience:

```sh
# add new repository key:
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654

# remove old repository key:
sudo apt-key del 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
```

Hope this helps you as well!

Update: If it does not, please watch these two:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/379190/apt-update-signatures-were-invalid-f42ed6fbab17c654/
- https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-gpg-key-expiration-incident/20669/3

Comment: to tkazik  

Thank you very much.
I was able to solve it!